Upload to Person or Group in Sharepoint using Excel VBA
I want to bulk upload a set of data in Excel containing fields with standard text data and an e-mail address.
I want the e-mail address to be uploaded into a Person or Group field, which in a SharePoint list automatically gets the person's Outlook details from the global address list. It's this field that causes the problem and won't accept just the e-mail address.
I'm using an ADODB Connection & Recordset in my code, but this doesn't seem to be up for the task and I'm happy to go in another direction.
Option Explicit

Sub AddItem()
    ' -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ' Add data to MS List
    '
    ' Requires a reference to "Microsoft ActiveX Data Object 6.1 Library" to insert a record into a SharePoint list
    ' Set in Tools -> References
    ' -------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

    Dim SQL As String
    Dim sht As String
    Dim url As String
    Dim lst As String
    Dim tbl As String
    Dim cnstr As String

    Dim i As Variant
    Dim n As Variant

    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    Dim userEmail As String
    Dim userInfo As String
    ' -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ' Update

    ' Excel Sheet Name with data
    sht = "Data"

    ' SharePoint Table Name
    tbl = "my sharepoint list"

    ' SharePoint Web Address (SharePointApplication)
    url = "my url/"

    ' SharePoint List Name - GUID
    lst = " guid "

    ' -------------------------------------------------------------------------

    ' SQL to connect to the Recordset
    SQL = "SELECT Top 1 * FROM [" & tbl & "];"

    ' Set the number of rows in Worksheet
    n = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets(sht).Range("A:A"))
    Sheets(sht).Select

    With cn
        .ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; WSS; IMEX=0; RetrieveIds=Yes; DATABASE=" & url & "; LIST={" & lst & "};"
        .Open
    End With

    rs.Open SQL, cn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic

    For i = 2 To 2 'n
        userEmail = Cells(i, 4).Value
        userInfo = GetUserInfoByEmail(userEmail)
        Cells(i, 8).Value = userInfo
        
        rs.AddNew
        rs.Fields("B_TYPE") = Cells(i, 1).Value
        rs.Fields("REF_ID") = Cells(i, 2).Value
        rs.Fields("SUB_ID") = Cells(i, 3).Value
        rs.Fields("TEL_01") = Cells(i, 5).Value
        rs.Fields("TEL_02") = Cells(i, 6).Value
        rs.Fields("EMAIL") = userInfo
        
        rs.Update
    Next i

    If CBool(rs.State And adStateOpen) = True Then rs.Close
    If CBool(cn.State And adStateOpen) = True Then cn.Close

    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub

Function GetUserInfoByEmail(email As String) As String
    Dim http As Object
    Dim url As String
    Dim responseText As String
    Dim userInfo As String
    
    ' SharePoint site URL
    url = "https://my url.com/_api/web/siteusers/getByEmail('" & email & "')"
    
    ' Create HTTP object
    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    
    ' Open connection to SharePoint
    http.Open "GET", url, False
    
    ' Set headers
    http.setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose"
    http.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json;odata=verbose"
    
    ' Send request
    http.Send
    
    ' Get response text
    responseText = http.responseText
    
    ' Parse JSON response to get user information (e.g., display name)
    userInfo = ParseUserInfoFromJSON(responseText)
    
    ' Return user information (e.g., display name)
    GetUserInfoByEmail = userInfo
    
    ' Clean up
    Set http = Nothing
End Function

Function ParseUserInfoFromJSON(jsonText As String) As String
    Dim displayNameStart As Long
    Dim displayNameEnd As Long
    Dim userInfo As String
    
    Cells(2, 7).Value = jsonText
    
    ' Example parsing logic; adjust based on SharePoint API response structure
    displayNameStart = InStr(jsonText, "LoginName") + Len("LoginName") + 2
    displayNameEnd = InStr(displayNameStart, jsonText, "Title:") - 1
    
    If displayNameStart > 0 And displayNameEnd > displayNameStart Then
        userInfo = Mid(jsonText, displayNameStart, displayNameEnd - displayNameStart)
    Else
        userInfo = "Error: Display name not found"
    End If
    
    ' Trim any unwanted characters from userInfo
    userInfo = Replace(userInfo, """", "")
    
    ParseUserInfoFromJSON = userInfo
End Function


With some googling you should find all of that.

"this doesn't seem to be up for the task" is not a useful description of the specific problem you're having when trying to get this to work.

It doesn't really matter why this isn't working. It's not and I've come to the conclusion that it never will. The idea behind this codeis that it’s gets a UserID from a global list, which is what is essentially uploaded in the process. The problem with this is that the Global e-mail address user ID is not the same as the ID in the specific list on SharePoint. During the upload into SharePoint it will look for the SharePoint ID and add those details. So every time a new row is added it will either use the incorrect details or not find the details at all. Which is why I need something else.

I went with Power Apps to update my data from a spreadsheet to a SharePoint List
